# How is MS C++ from VS2010 behaving differently from other compilers in this case?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've fixed my problem here, but I don't understand why it works, or whether MS have it right here. I didn't write this code, but I maintain it. Its part of a DSP application that handles data as bit vectors and occaisionally has to pack and unpack them from bytes.

These are the packing and unpacking methods

```
template<class TData> void CVector<TData>::Enqueue(uint32_t iInformation, const int iNumOfBits)
{
    /* Enqueue bits in bit array */
    for (int i = 0; i < iNumOfBits; i++)
    {
        /* We want to put the bits on the array with the MSB first */
        /* Shift one bit to mask next bit at LSB-position */
        operator[](iBitArrayCounter + iNumOfBits - i - 1) = _BINARY(iInformation & 1);
        iInformation >>= 1;
    }
    iBitArrayCounter += iNumOfBits;
}

template<class TData> uint32_t CVector<TData>::Separate(const int iNumOfBits)
{
    uint32_t iInformation;
    if (iBitArrayCounter + iNumOfBits > iVectorSize)
        return 0;
    /* Separate out bits from bit-array */
    iInformation = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < iNumOfBits; i++)
    {
        /* MSB comes first, therefore shift left */
        iInformation <<= 1;
        iInformation |= pData[iBitArrayCounter + i] & 1;
    }
    iBitArrayCounter += iNumOfBits;
    return iInformation;
}
```

Where

```
typedef unsigned char _BINARY;
```

Now this has been working for many years on successive MS compilers and gcc on Windows, Mac and linux. It still works on all compilers in debug mode. In MSVC9 (I think thats the version for Visual Studio 2010) in Release mode I had to change the line in the Enqueue method from:

```
        operator[](iBitArrayCounter + iNumOfBits - i - 1) = _BINARY(iInformation & 1);
```

to:

```
        if(iInformation & 1)
            operator[](iBitArrayCounter + iNumOfBits - i - 1) = 1;
        else
            operator[](iBitArrayCounter + iNumOfBits - i - 1) = 0;
```

The class was instantiated with TData = _BINARY. The problem seemed to be a sign extension but the Enqueue and Separate were not symettric. For example 65 got encoded and then separated to 193.

Here is a link to the actual code http://drm.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/drm/drm/common/util/Vector.h?view=log. 1.8 is the fix.

I just realised that the _BINARY macro should be replaced by TData, but in this case it shouldn't matter as the class is instantiated with _BINARY anyway.

Comment: Did you try using parenthesis around that logical and? `(iInformation & 1)`. Maybe something weird is happening on VS2010 and the `&` is being applied to the assignment's return value.

Comment: Actually its there - I just checked in CVS and my reconstruction of before the change was not perfect. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Does it work if you use `(iInformation & 1u)`? That is, explicitly make the subexpression unsigned.

Comment: Clarification:  I seem to remember that as per the standard, bitwise operations on signed types are implementation-defined. Furthermore, the type promotion rules are such that (*unsigned type* **operand** *signed type*) will cause the unsigned operand to be converted to signed first. Your subexpression will thus be between two signed ints. Still, seems like a compiler bug, as pretty much all implementations these days allow bitwise arithmetic with 2's complement rules.

Comment: Will try that later, but Phil I think you have put your finger on it - the literal 1 is signed and getting sign extended. What I still don't understand is how the same compiler can do different things in release and debug modes.

Comment: I tried a small test program to check out the 1u suggestion and it doesn't replicate the problem. I'm going to check the qmake generated project files for optimisation settings.

Comment: Don't know if it's related (and it's nearly a year after this question), but this ended up in my inbox. It's a bug in the VC++ compiler that relates to the shift operators, but wonder if whatever caused this error impacted other bitwise operations: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2820057/en-us?sd=rss&spid=1117

Comment: Could be. I might try comparing the 2010 and 2012 behaviours. Code has work around now though.